# Dynamically choose a view in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have an android app, and i want it to have two views which are similar to one another.
For example :

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="OK" />
```

and

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK" />
```

notice that the only change is that i removed the centerHorizontal line. but this is a simplified example.

Now, i want to create an app, that sometimes (ex- using a random func) uses view A and sometimes uses view B.

Is it possible to do this "views switch" at runtime?
Is it possible to build this app using the two views (notice that the button should have the same ID, i don't want to implement the logic twice)?

thanks a lot!

Comment: sure you can toggle between gravities, can't you?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I imagine to do that is:

- Having each button in its own layout file.
- Inflate the corresponding based on your function result.
- Append it to the view.

Sample code:

**button_a.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="OK" />
```

**button_b.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK_2" />
```

**Your activity:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    Button button;

    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        button = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_a, null);
    } else {
        button = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_b, null);
    }

    /* ...
       Set listeners to the button and other stuff 
       ...
    */

    //find the view to wich you want to append the button
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

    //append the button
    view.addView(button);
}
```

If you want this to happen dynamically (i.e. not in the `onCreate`, but after some user input) you can always remove the button from layout, and inflate a new random-chosen one.

Hope this helps!